# La consulta se envía apenas entrar a la página

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php5

La consulta se envía apenas entrar a la página, no detecta los if anteriores de los post vacíos y la verdad hace dos días estoy con esto. En el mismo php tengo el formulario.

```
<?php
include '../scripts/conexion.php';
$u = (isset($_POST['usuarioingresado']) ? $_POST['usuarioingresado'] : 1);
$e = (isset($_POST['emailingresado']) ? $_POST['emailingresado'] : 1);
$c = (isset($_POST['contraingresada']) ? $_POST['contraingresada'] : 1);
$btn = (isset($_POST['btn']) ? $_POST['btn'] : 1);  
if($u==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = ''Tenésque poner un usuario.'</script>";}
if($e==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Tenés que poner un email.'</script>";}
if($c==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Tenés que poner una contraseña.'</script>";}
if($btn==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'No has presionado el botón de enviar.'</script>";}
$ce = strtoupper(hash('whirlpool', $c));
$bR = "SELECT * FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = '$u' and Email = '$e'";
$r = $con->query($bR);
$c1 = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if($c1==0){$u1 = $con->query("INSERT INTO sv_nicks (Contra, Email, Nick) VALUES ('$ce', '$e', '$u')");echo "Te registraste correctamente con estos datos:<br>Nombre: $u.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>Email: $e.";}
if($c1==1){echo "O los datos ya fueron utilizados o debés completar el formulario de una manera correcta.";}
?>
```

Me puede llegar hasta mandar una consulta así:

```html
Te registraste correctamente con estos datos:
Nombre: .
Contraseña: .
Email: .
```

Comment: El problema que tienes es que $c1 siempre va a tener como valor 0 . El registro no existe.   Y si es 0 estas ejecutando el query del insert sin importar lo que tengas en los POST .

Comment: Está mal hecha tu lógica, siempre va a entrar a las query por que no hay un `else` o un `die` por lo tanto si entra a los `if` y los valora, pero en ningún momento estás diciendo que se termine el script. Te preparo una respuesta más elaborada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra forma de resolver tu problema sería creando directamente en las evaluaciones ternarias una estructura de datos. Es decir, un array asociativo que voy a llamar `$arrDatos`, que sea una representación del estado general de los datos que estás manejando.

Esto permitirá escribir un código más claro, menos repetitivo y más fácil de mantener. Por ejemplo si se agregan nuevas condiciones a evaluar solamente tendrías que agregarlas al array de datos.

Si observas bien, aquí es posible saber con esta línea de código si hay algún error:

```
if(array_column($arrDatos, 'msg')) {
```

y luego obtener los diferentes mensajes de error en una variable mediante:

```
    $msgs=implode("<br />",array_column($arrDatos, 'msg'));
```

y usar esa única variable para invocar una sola vez el script y poner el dato (o los datos) en el contenedor HTML.

El código sería este:

```
$arrDatos=array();

$arrDatos['usr']  = (!empty($_POST['usuarioingresado']) ) ? array ('data'=>$_POST['usuarioingresado']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tenés que poner un usuario.');
$arrDatos['mail'] = (!empty($_POST['emailingresado']) )   ? array ('data'=>$_POST['emailingresado'])   : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tenés que poner un email.');
$arrDatos['pwd']  = (!empty($_POST['contraingresada']) )  ? array ('data'=>$_POST['contraingresada'])  : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tenés que poner una contraseña.');
$arrDatos['btn']  = (!empty($_POST['btn']) )              ? array ('data'=>$_POST['btn'])              : array('id'=> 1);

if(array_column($arrDatos, 'msg')) {
    $msgs=implode("<br />",array_column($arrDatos, 'msg'));
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '".$msgs."'</script>";
} else {
  $ce = strtoupper( hash('whirlpool', $arrDatos['pwd']['data']) );
  $u=$arrDatos['usr']['data'];
  $e=$arrDatos['mail']['data'];
  $bR = "SELECT * FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = '$u' and Email = '$e'";
  $r  = $con->query($bR);
  $c1 = mysqli_num_rows( $r );
  if( $c1 === 0 ){
    $u1 = $con->query("INSERT INTO sv_nicks (Contra, Email, Nick) VALUES ('$ce', '$e', '$u')");
    echo "Te registraste correctamente con estos datos:<br>Nombre: $u.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>Email: $e.";

  }else{
      echo "O los datos ya fueron utilizados o debés completar el formulario de una manera correcta.";
  }
}
```

Es simplemente una forma distinta de enfocar el problema, tratándolo de una forma *modular*  por decirlo de alguna manera.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Fue la única que entendí y funcionó, definí la variable $c y ya estaba, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Morderisk la contraseña estará en `$arrDatos['pwd']['data']`, aunque no creo que sea buena idea mostrarla (en un escenario real). Otra cosa que quería comentarte es que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Cuando puedas lee sobre ese riesgo y sobre la forma de prevenirlo mediante el uso de consultas preparadas. Saludos.

Comment: Te has ganado mis respetos.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla de hacer esto es con funciones, te dejo un esquema que te puede ayudar a organizar mejor el código.

```
function insert_data_DB() {
    // Aqui va la captura de los valores insertados
    // y los procesos de esos valores para luego ser insertados en la base
    $u = $_POST['usuarioingresado'];
    $e = $_POST['emailingresado'];
    .
    .
    .
    $query = "INSERT INTO sv_nicks ...";
    if($con->query($query)) {
        echo 'Valores insertados correctamente';
    } else {
        echo 'Ha ocurrido un error insertando los datos';
    }
}

function input_form() {
    // AQUI VA EL FORMULARIO 
    // También vale cerrar el php (?>) para escribir el html puro y al final abrirlo
    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="usuarioingresado" placeholder="Nombre" required>';
    .
    .
    .
    echo '</form>';
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Si esta presente el metodo POST, o sea que se ha presionado el boton de "Submit"
    insert_data_DB();
} else {
    // Si no se ha enviado nada, cargar el formulario
    input_form();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe una gran diferencia entre usar `isset` y `empty` puesto que se evaluan dos cosas distintas. Mira este ejemplo

```
$foo = "";

if(empty($foo)) // true por que $foo (cadena vacía) es considerado empty
if(isset($foo)) // true por que $foo está declarada

if(empty($bar)) //true por que $bar no existe
if(isset($bar)) //false por que $bar no existe
```

Entonces, yo recomendaría el uso de `empty()` y la primera parte quedaría así

```
include '../scripts/conexion.php';
$u   = empty( $_REQUEST['usuarioingresado'] ) ? $_REQUEST['usuarioingresado'] : 1;
$e   = empty( $_REQUEST['emailingresado'] )   ? $_REQUEST['emailingresado'] : 1;
$c   = empty( $_REQUEST['contraingresada'] )  ? $_REQUEST['contraingresada'] : 1;
$btn = empty( $_REQUEST['btn'] ) ? $_REQUEST['btn'] : 1;
```

Ahora, como te dije en mi comentario de tu pregunta, estas haciendo todas tus validaciones y retornando scripts con errores pero nunca está terminando el script, este continua por que no hay una instrucción para detenerse tipo `exit()` o `die()`
Este problema se puede resolver con un `else` puesto que necesitas mostrar que es lo que está mal ( Aunque siempre verás el último error de arriba hacia abajo por el envío de scripts al front en la misma variable, pero eso es un tema de frontend )

Ahora, la segunda parte la podemos solucionar así

```
if( $u === 1 || $e === 1 || $c === 1 || $btn === 1 ){

  if($u==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = ''Tenésque poner un usuario.'</script>";}
  if($e==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Tenés que poner un email.'</script>";}
  if($c==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Tenés que poner una contraseña.'</script>";}
  if($btn==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'No has presionado el botón de enviar.'</script>";}

}else{
  $ce = strtoupper( hash('whirlpool', $c) );
  $bR = "SELECT * FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = '$u' and Email = '$e'";
  $r  = $con->query($bR);
  $c1 = mysqli_num_rows( $r );
  if( $c1 === 0 ){
    $u1 = $con->query("INSERT INTO sv_nicks (Contra, Email, Nick) VALUES ('$ce', '$e', '$u')");
    echo "Te registraste correctamente con estos datos:<br>Nombre: $u.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>Email: $e.";

  }else{
      echo "O los datos ya fueron utilizados o debés completar el formulario de una manera correcta.";
  }

}
```

Primero tuvimos que preguntar si todas las variables por POST tienen algún tipo de error, cual fuera, entonces no permitiremos que se hagan las querys. Respecto al render de cada error ahora si lo ponemos como tu lo tenías, reitero ahí hay un error de lógica con el frontend.

Si todas las variables son distintas de 1 entonces podemos continuar con las consultas a la base de datos.
La parte de las consultas e inserción de datos tiene varios errores, tanto de lógica, como de seguridad y consumo de datos, hay prácticas que te pueden salvar el pellejo más adelante, pero por lo pronto así debería de funcionar como quieres.

**Este es el code completo**

```
<?php
include '../scripts/conexion.php';
$u   = empty( $_REQUEST['usuarioingresado'] ) ? $_REQUEST['usuarioingresado'] : 1;
$e   = empty( $_REQUEST['emailingresado'] )   ? $_REQUEST['emailingresado'] : 1;
$c   = empty( $_REQUEST['contraingresada'] )  ? $_REQUEST['contraingresada'] : 1;
$btn = empty( $_REQUEST['btn'] ) ? $_REQUEST['btn'] : 1;

if( $u === 1 || $e === 1 || $c === 1 || $btn === 1 ){

  if($u==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = ''Tenésque poner un usuario.'</script>";}
  if($e==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Tenés que poner un email.'</script>";}
  if($c==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Tenés que poner una contraseña.'</script>";}
  if($btn==1){echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'No has presionado el botón de enviar.'</script>";}

}else{
  $ce = strtoupper( hash('whirlpool', $c) );
  $bR = "SELECT * FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = '$u' and Email = '$e'";
  $r  = $con->query($bR);
  $c1 = mysqli_num_rows( $r );
  if( $c1 === 0 ){
    $u1 = $con->query("INSERT INTO sv_nicks (Contra, Email, Nick) VALUES ('$ce', '$e', '$u')");
    echo "Te registraste correctamente con estos datos:<br>Nombre: $u.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>Email: $e.";

  }else{
      echo "O los datos ya fueron utilizados o debés completar el formulario de una manera correcta.";
  }

}


?>
```

Comment: Los empty me dejan advertencias de variables no definidas.

Comment: Aver, muestrame el error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/veAWvjP

Comment: Cambia los super arreglos $_POST por $_REQUEST, edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Sigue dando los mis errores, ¿tengo que cambiar el method del formulario? Lo tengo así <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"></form>.

Comment: No, REQUEST no es un método del protocolo HTTP, es una forma en cómo PHP engloba $_POST y $_GET. Agrega esta línea `error_reporting(0);` antes que todo el código, esto deshabilitará los errores y notices momentaneamente.

Comment: sería `!empty($variable)? $variable : 1` ... "if not empty"